# ASP.net MaskEditExtender stops working when parent div is display:none

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, shadowbox

I have started using the MaskEditExtender.  The following works fine:

```
<div class="row">  
  <asp:Label ID="lblStartTime" Text="Start Time: " runat="server" />
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartTime" runat="server" />
  <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="mskStartTime" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false" TargetControlID="txtStartTime" runat="server" AcceptAMPM="true" Mask="99:99"  MaskType="Time" />
</div>
```

And the mask works perfectly.  But as soon as I set display to none on the following, the mask doesn't work:

```
<div class="row" style="display:none">  
  <asp:Label ID="lblStartTime" Text="Start Time: " runat="server" />
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartTime" runat="server" />
  <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="mskStartTime" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false" TargetControlID="txtStartTime" runat="server" AcceptAMPM="true" Mask="99:99"  MaskType="Time" />
</div>
```

I need this to work because I am using a shadowbox type of plugin so I need to hide and show this.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need it while display:none is applied since the user can't access that textbox. Does it not start working after the content is displayed?

Comment: The inputs are hidden until a link is clicked and then the inputs are displayed.  Once I unhide it, it stops working.  But if I never hide it then it will work.  I'm baffled.